Flutter iOS Build Failed - Error During Build for iOS Platform
I'm facing an issue with my Flutter app when trying to build it for iOS. The Android build works fine, but the iOS build fails with an error related to the iOS simulator. The app is built using Flutter on macOS with Rosetta.
Environment Details

Flutter Version: 3.7.12 (stable)
Xcode Version: 16.0 macOS Version:15.0.1 (Darwin arm64 under Rosetta)
iOS Device: iPhone 14 Pro (Simulator, iOS 16.4)

Commands Run
I tried running:
flutter run -d "iPhone 14 Pro" --no-sound-null-safety

Error Log
Here’s the error message from the console:
The plugin `flutter_webview_plugin` uses a deprecated version of the Android embedding. ...
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 14 Pro in debug mode...
Running Xcode build...
Xcode build done.
Failed to build iOS app.
Error output from Xcode build:
    xcodebuild: error: Unable to find a destination matching the provided destination specifier:
        { id:33D3C63C-DE24-4B1C-8FF1-7C139930C7C7 }
Available destinations for the "Runner" scheme:
    { platform:macOS, arch:arm64, id:00008112-000804180A33A01E, name:My Mac }
    { platform:macOS, arch:x86_64, id:00008112-000804180A33A01E, name:My Mac }
    { platform:macOS, name:Any Mac }

xcrun Output
When I run xcrun simctl list devices, I can see the iPhone 14 Pro simulator listed as "Booted" with the correct ID. Here is the relevant part:
-- iOS 16.4 --
iPhone 14 Pro (33D3C63C-DE24-4B1C-8FF1-7C139930C7C7) (Booted)

Clean the project cache:
flutter clean

Install dependencies:
flutter pub get

Navigate to the iOS folder:
cd ios
Install CocoaPods dependencies:
pod install

Return to the main project folder:
cd ..

Build the project for iOS:
flutter build ios
Run the app:.
flutter run

This sequence should help resolve issues with dependencies and build a fresh version for iOS. Hope this helps!

I already tried this but still getting the same issue.

try creating new project and copying all the code
